# Exclude file name when using glob and array_slice

Tags: php, arrays, glob

This has to be simple: I'm using glob to build a list of links to all files in a directory (i.e., index.php, somefile.php, someotherfile.php), but I need to exclude the file name/path `index.php` before the `array_slice`.

For some reason, in these two examples, I can exclude `index.php` after the `array_alice`, but not before. What am I doing wrong?

This doesn't remove the filename/path `index.php`:

```
chdir('/dir/tree/');

foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {

$files[$path] = filemtime($path);

} arsort($files);

if($path != 'index.php') {

foreach (array_slice($files, 0, 3) as $path => $timestamp) {

print '<a href="'. $path .'">'. $path .'</a><br />';
}
}
```

This removes `index.php`, but it is after the array_alice, so I get two links printed instead of three:

```
chdir('/dir/tree/');

foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {

$files[$path] = filemtime($path);

} arsort($files);

foreach (array_slice($files, 0, 3) as $path => $timestamp) {

if($path != 'index.php') {

print '<a href="'. $path .'">'. $path .'</a><br />';
}
}
```

Comment: You using `$path` after loop, so it always take last item. Put it in first loop.

Comment: Can you add an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your check after loop.

```
<php
foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {
//---------------------------^
    $files[$path] = filemtime($path);
}
arsort($files);

if($path != 'index.php') {}
//---^
```

Put it in your loop like this:

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {
    if($path == 'index.php') {
        continue;
    }
    $files[$path] = filemtime($path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I had tried a `continue` before `$path` conditional but didn't get it to work.